# How to cut/sampling by csv filesize on pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am `df` is pyspark dataframe, I need to cut by size on production environment data, for example 100 MB

Here's the script I usualy use (for not cutting scenario)

`df.coalesce(1).write.csv(output_path+"/folder_name", header=True, mode='overwrite')`

How to cut some initial row (for example 100 MB)

I use `.limit(10000)` when I create df when I want to minimize file, what I need is to investigate how big file my infra can save, because cutting dataframe is still sampling and I want as much as sample possible

Comment: don't know how to control by data size but this option can control by #records.  `.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000)`

Comment: I use `.limit(10000)` when I create df, what I need is to investigate how big file my infra can save

Comment: sure, the size is dependent on the infra you have.  Although, note that `limit(10000)` is down sampling, however, `write.option('maxRecordsPerFile', 10000).csv` is not down sampling. It still saves all records but it partitions into multiple files such that each file contains maximum of 10000 records.